# How to set minimum height for a div?

Tags: css

I have a page in which expanding content flows out of the holding div, the relevant CSS is below as well.  Simply removing the `height:510px` line will allow the `div` to expand as needed.  However, new users who have no content will not have any height and the page will look unblanced.  How do I set a minimum height?

```
.Bb1
  {
  width:680px;
  height:510px;
  background-color:#ffffff; 
  float:left;
  border-right:3px solid #edefed;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

CSS allows a "min-height" property. This can be used to set the minimum height of the div you're talking about.

```
#div-id { min-height: 100px; }
```

Answer (score 25):

Incase you want to set a minimum/maximum height and minimum/maximum width to a `div`, CSS allows the specific feature.

To set the minimum width of the `div` or any other class/id/element, use;

```
min-width: 150px;
```

To set the minimum height of the `div` or any other class/id/element, use;

```
min-height: 300px;
```

Similarly for setting maximum width and height of a `div` or any other class/id/element, use;

```
max-width: 600px;
max-height: 600px;
```

**Important:**

For your `div` to *expand freely* in height and width after data is available for users; you will have to set the width/height to `auto` **immediately** after you have set the `min-width` or `min-height`.

```
min-width: 300px;
width: auto;

min-height: 100px;
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
min-height:510px;
```

css has a min-height attribute

Answer (score 3):

Here is d way through which you can set min height of a div

```
<div id="bb1" style="min-height:200px;>
    .....
</div>
```

or apply

```
#bb1{
    min-height:200px;
}
```

if you have used **class**

like

```
<div class="bb1">
```

in div then use

```
.bb1{
    min-height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.comments { min-height:650px;height:auto; }


<div class="comments">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```css
.minHeight {
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* IMPORTANT -- always set 'height: auto;' immediately after the min-height attribute */
}
```

```html
<div class="minHeight">
  this div has a min-height attribute
</div>
```